# How To Prevent Tab Hell With Visual Studio And FireFox Debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, firefox

How do I keep VS from opening a new tab in Firefox every time I hit F5 to debug a web application?  I would *really* like it to re-use the same tab.

Comment: Yep - I'd also be interested how to do this in chrome.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This may not work for you but, in a project's properties on the Web tab there is a setting described as "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application."  All the developers at my company have this set and then just use bookmarks to load our pages.

Comment: Cool, I think that is about as close as I can get right now. Just have to look up the port VS assigns and your set. Not perfect, but its a lot closer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think about that.  We run IIS on each workstation and have the virtual directory point to our development path.  So the port isn't a problem for us.

Comment: Yeah, if it's run on a development system, just pick the directory it's running. Great idea +1.

Comment: Update: If you are using the dev server, just right click on the tray icon and click "Open in Browser". No port lookups. :-)