# How to prevent Firefox from switching to the new tab when starting a web app in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, firefox, firefox-addon

How to prevent Firefox from switching to the new tab when starting a web app in Visual Studio? I would like to stay at the tab I am currently reading instead of switching back to it. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247908/how-to-prevent-tab-hell-with-visual-studio-and-firefox-debugging). However I don't want to open a new browser window.

I tried several Firefox extensions like 'Tab Utilities', 'Tab Mix Pro' and 'Tabloc'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try disabling tabs Tools->Options->Tabs->un-check the "Open new window in new tab instead" and see if the result suits you. Also you could try clicking the reload button on the browser, and using 'Attach to process' in VS to aspnet_wp.exe

Comment: I don't see a Tabs option. I don't see how a reload does anything. The browser already switched to the new tab. The attach to process is a big hassle. I run the app tens of times a day. The solution seems to be from Firefox side, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Can I ask you why you need to do this??? :)

Comment: @Nour I am reading a web page and want to stay on it when VS is starting to run an app.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine you want to step through your code on the current page your working on without re-setting up authentication and environment variables.

Here are the options I found, unfortunately I could not find a Firefox plugin that would satisfy your needs.

1. Disable visual studio from opening a new window when debugging by going to **project settings -> Web -> Check Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application**. Then reload Firefox
2. Just attach to an existing process through visual studio: **Debug -> Attach To Process -> click show processes from all users -> search for WebDev.WebServer.exe (w3wp.exe if hosted from IIS) -> attach**. From there just reload the page and Firefox should hook into your application. If you want a quicker way you can make a macro, demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9037669/810850)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try adjusting a setting in Firefox on the "about:config" webpage.

Try setting [browser.link.open_newwindow](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow) to 1, which tells Firefox to "open new tabs in current tab/window". This will affect regular browsing on Firefox as well, but it should give you the desired effect when debugging from Visual Studio.